# ::CKEDITOR 5 :: Multiple instances for static and dynamically created divs and single Editor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CKEDITOR 5 Superbuild.

Having table with multiple tds with class name as `.text` and inside each td, I have div[contenteditable] set as true.

I am trying to use multiple editors in same page with same class/attribute and always need to show only one editor.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/wu14opvf/53/)**

**Isuue:**
Getting multiple editors on clicking any div each time.
[image]

**Desired results:**

- OnClick of any contenteditable div, it should show editor with given option
- For eg: If I click on first div, it should show properties of that perticular div, and by clicking on second div, it should its properties only. That means, I need to show only one instance anytime.
- If I generate dynamically new div by clicking on `+ Add new` button also it should be same.

[image]

```js
$('#ck-fixed-toolbar').hide();
$(document).on("click", "table td.text div[contenteditable]", function (e) {
CKEDITOR.ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('table td.text div[contenteditable]'), {
  toolbar: {
    items: [
      'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough',
    ],
    shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
  },
  placeholder: '',
  removePlugins: ['CKBox', 'CKFinder', 'EasyImage', 'RealTimeCollaborativeComments', 'RealTimeCollaborativeTrackChanges', 'RealTimeCollaborativeRevisionHistory', 'PresenceList', 'Comments', 'TrackChanges', 'TrackChangesData', 'RevisionHistory', 'Pagination', 'WProofreader', 'MathType', 'SlashCommand', 'Template', 'DocumentOutline', 'FormatPainter', 'TableOfContents', 'PasteFromOfficeEnhanced']
}).then(editor => {
  const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector('#ck-fixed-toolbar');
  toolbarContainer.appendChild(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element);
});
});

$(document).on("click", "table td.text div[contenteditable]", function (e) {
$('#ck-fixed-toolbar').show();
});

$(document).on('click', '#addNewContent', function(){
$('#ck-fixed-toolbar').hide();
$('table').append('<tr><td class="text"><div contenteditable="true">Dynamically created content</div></td></tr>');
})
```

```css
body{font-family:Verdana;font-size:13px;}
#ck-fixed-toolbar{min-height:50px;}
table,td{border:1px solid #cccc;border-collapse:collapse}
#addNewContent{margin-top:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/39.0.2/super-build/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div id="ck-fixed-toolbar"></div>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="text">
            <div contenteditable="true">
                Content 1 lorem ipsum dolar sit amet
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text">
            <div contenteditable="true">
                Content 2 lorem ipsum dolar sit amet
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="addNewContent">+ Add new</button>
```